# Display xml in html?

Tags: html, xml

I get xml from jQuery ajax and found that you can use the following to show the xml:

```
$.ajax.({...
...
success: function(xml, textStatus, jqXHR) {    
$("#mydiv").text(jqXHR.responseText);
```

Is it possible to show nice formated xml in a tree structure, with just jQuery and HTML in Chrome or Firefox?

Do you know how?

Comment: You want to display XML content just as text within a web page, or as the entire page (i.e. server up an entire XML document to a browser)?

Comment: If you want to dislpay xml code on a webpage, you could use the google code prettifier (http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/). It will display the xml code with syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thanks, I did come across that one - but left it again as the following did not work: <pre class="prettyprint lang-xml"> and $(".prettyprint").text(jqXHR.responseText);

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- HTML -->
<pre id="display"></pre>

// JS
var xmlStr = (new window.XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlNode);
document.getElementById('display').innerText = xmlStr;
```